# Performing a service call on app start up in a Xamarin built iOS app

Tags: service, xamarin.ios, startup

Basically, I need to call a service to perform a simple get operation in my iOS app that I have built using Xamarin. The problem is I need to do this when the app fires up.

I have an in-house app that is being distributed to employees, and I need to call a service when the app starts to check for a newer version. How would I do this?

Comment: I should mention I already know how to do a call to service. My question is where would the best place to do this in a Xamarin iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Splash screen that is having the same layout as the LaunchScreen. Set the Splash screen as the first screen to show. Then you can call to your service from the Splash screen during ViewDidLoad.

If you plan to show dialog to force user to update app, you might have risk that Apple reject your app. [Apple rejected app because I am forcing users to update their app version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310731/apple-rejected-app-because-i-am-forcing-users-to-update-their-app-version)

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it in **[FinishedLaunching](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary/)** delegate in AppDelegate.cs file where is used to setup your app. Then your new version checking service will start when user launches your app.

As you are using an in-house app which doesn't need to be reviewed by Apple, so there's no rejection risk on forcing update which @lowleetak mentioned.

Comment: Hi @DeveryDay, did my answer help you?